# Magento 1 : Custom address attribute is not appearing in order using custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, third-party-module

I've installed a simple module that creates a new attribute in the customer address.
I'm able to see it both on frontend and backend, but once the order is completed it's nor present in the order informations. I've no idea how to make it appear.
Probably a simple task but i'm new to magento.

**This is checkout page, the field "Codice Fiscale 2" is visible**
[image: This is checkout page, the field "Codice Fiscale 2" is visible]

**When the order is placed the field is not visible anymore.**
[image]